# UIImagePickerController does not display GIFs correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, gif

I am using the `UIImagePickerController` for my app. With that, users can pick all different types of visual media - images, GIFs & videos (movies).

However, `GIFs` are displayed as Images in the "`Edit image`" screen, that comes with the `UIImagePickerController` by default. They do not move.

I am not sure, but is there a way to tell the `imagePickerController` to play the GIFs in the "`Edit image`" screen?

Here are some images that show you what I mean:

[image: Unanimated gif in the image album]

[image: GIF still not animated when user selects it and gets to this screen]

Here you can see, that neither of the two screens from the `UIImagePickerViewController` display `GIFs` correctly?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to tell the imagePickerController to play the GIFs in the "Edit image" screen

No. There is no built in display of animated gifs in any public API.

Comment: Do you think Apple will add that in the future? Or do I really have to create a custom Image Picker controller?

Comment: Knowing what Apple will do is outside my pay grade. So is knowing what you have to do, actually. Personally I would just accept that iOS doesn’t do animated GIFs.

Comment: My guess? Probably not. (Who really knows what Apple plans going forward?) GIF support in iOS is very... sparse. `UIImagePickerController` is very mature anymore. It appears that Apple's plans this year is to port pieces of `UIKit` to work on macOS. Read the tea leaves - your best bet is to find a better alternative than a stock `UIImagePIckerController`.

Answer (score 0):

I create a separate button for choosing video VS choosing GIFs.  That way I can set "allowsEditing" to true for video and false for the GIFs.  When you set allowsEditing to false, the GIFs are at least animated once you have selected them.  Other than this, I have found no way to improve the behavior of the UIImagePicker.

Comment: How can I specify that the UIImagePicker should only show Gifs? So far I was only able to distinguish between image vs. video?

Comment: You can't...  At least you can't seem to.  The only two filter types it accepts are photo and video.  Animated GIFS (unfortunately) are considered in the photo category.  In my app, single photos are quite useless and I haven't figured out a way to have the image picker not show them.  The best I can do is to tell the user to choose a different photo.  And, to make matters worse, I can't seem to figure out how to know an image is an animated GIF without opening it first.